# grid row with dropdown

Tags: asp.net

How to make a first two rows in a gridview as dropdown?. I am using itemtemplate. If I use asp dropdown in itemtemplate the first two columns become drop down but I need to have first two rows alone drop down. Any suggestions or examples please.

Comment: ok i want to add adropdown to one particular cell in a grid

Answer (score 0):

Add dropdown using code 
create a bound field and add dropdown to it using code and while filling check the status of the datatable check the condition of datatable row count and fill add rest leave blank

Comment: ok i want to add adropdown to one particular cell in a grid how can we achieve that?

Comment: The logic will be same my friend